# mongodb java driver 3.4.x geoquery

Tags: java, mongodb

I need help with geospatial query.

I have two collections: Points and MultiPolygon

I would like to retrieve all Points contained in a specific MultiPolygon.

The structure of two elements are:

```
{_id : someID, "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 12.54638671875, 41.85319643776675 ] }}

{_id: "id", "type": "MultiPolygon",
"coordinates": [[[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]]],[[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]],[[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]]}
```

To do that i make a query on Multipolygon collection in order to retrieve the shape that I have to use to make a geoIntersect query but without any success.

In particular I have problems to convert coordinates of Datacenter documents to BSON element required by Filter class.

Please could someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MultiPolygon object of the MongoDB Driver like this

```
List<PolygonCoordinates> polygonList = new ArrayList<>();
// Add your Positions in polygonList.
MultiPolygon multiPolygon = new MultiPolygon(polygonList);

this.mongoCollection.find(geoIntersects("geometry", multiPolygon));
```

You could find more information on the MongoDB JavaDoc : https://static.javadoc.io/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.2.0-rc0/com/mongodb/client/model/geojson/MultiPolygon.html

Comment: if i answer to your question, please upvote my post and click on the answer icon ;)